# How to distinguish multiple Tomcat clusters from one another?

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64
**HTTP Server**: Apache 2.2x
**Tomcat**: Apache 7.x
**JVM**: openJDK 1.7

We need to create a clustered Tomcat 7 environment. We have have been doing a lot of reading and **need clarification on how to distinguish clusters from one another**. We read *about* having mutliple clusters but we haven't seen a real example of how to *configure* multiple clusters.

For simplicity sake, how does one configure this environment?

```
Node 01 - Apache HTTP
  running mod_jk using load balancer

Node 02 - Tomcat Server
  running PROD application instance (Cluster PROD)
  running TEST application instance (Cluster TEST)
  running DEV application instance (Cluster DEV)

Node 03 - Tomcat Server
  running PROD application instance (Cluster PROD)
  running TEST application instance (Cluster TEST)
  running DEV application instance (Cluster DEV)
```

We don't want the session data to be shared between the different clusters. In other words, we don't want the PROD (Production) cluster information being shared with the TEST and DEV clusters (and vice-versa).

I think I understand that this statement in the **server.xml** is key to distinguishing each cluster instance. Please correct me if I am wrong:

```
<Membership
  className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
  address="228.0.0.4"
  port="45564" frequency="500"
  dropTime="3000"
/>
```

Therefore, do I just need to change the address field to something unique for each cluster? Example:

```
<!-- Cluster PROD -->
<Membership
  className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
  address="228.0.0.4"
  port="45564" frequency="500"
  dropTime="3000"
/>

<!-- Cluster TEST -->
<Membership
  className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
  address="228.0.0.5"
  port="45564" frequency="500"
  dropTime="3000"
/>

<!-- Cluster DEV -->
<Membership
  className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
  address="228.0.0.6"
  port="45564" frequency="500"
  dropTime="3000"
/>
```

Is there any other advice or gotcha's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html

You've correctly identified the [multicast IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address) as the method by which clusters find out about members.  You could also use different ports.

> If you want a QA cluster and a production cluster, the easiest config is to have the QA cluster be on a separate multicast address/port combination the the production cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple clusters mean multiple Tomcat instances. In your case, node 02 and node 03 will be one cluster, you don't need to define another. So use only one `Cluster` tag (and with this, only one `Membership` tag is needed), and all three webapps' sessions will be synchronized between the tomcat instances (the webapps have to have the `<distributable />` tag in their web.xml for this).